# C# cant cast a class property directly

Tags: c#, .net, casting

I have a class `ResultTable` that inherits from Result

```
public class ResultTable : Result
```

Result is a property of `ResultWrapper`.

```
public class ResultWrapper
{
   public Result Result { get; set; }
}
```

When I do:

```
ResultTable myCastedItem = myResult.Result as ResultTable;
```

I get the item in `myCastedItem`, but i want to do it directly like:

```
If ( (ResultTable)myResult.Result.DataRows) // It does not let me.
```

`DataRows` is a member of `ResultTable` but not of `Result`.

Comment: `((ResultTable)myResult).DataRows`?

Comment: Thanks i accidently casted the member DataRows instead of the object above it, I will close the question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ITS EASY ONE, I ACCIDENTLY CASTED THE MEMBER AND NOT THE CLASS. SILLY QUESTION

Answer (score 2):

You are just missing some braces:

```
if (((ResultTable)myResult.Result).DataRows) // It will let you ;-).
```

Answer (score 1):

You are casting wrong property.

```
(ResultTable)myResult.Result.DataRows
```

You need to change it to:

```
((ResultTable)myResult.Result).DataRows
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to surround your cast with braces like this:

```
((ResultTable)myResult.Result).DataRows
```

or you can use safe cast (remember, that as can return null):

```
var casted = (myResult.Result as ResultTable);
if(casted!=null)
   casted.DataRows;
```

Or, with c# 6 .? operator:

```
(myResult.Result as ResultTable).?DataRows
```

Comment: If you cast with the `as` operator you will not get an `InvalidCastException`, but the result of the cast will be null anyway. At that point, when you access the `DataRows` property you'll have a `NullReferenceException`...

Comment: @PaoloTedesco, yes, forgot about this, i'll fix my answer